# Does the coating(tin/ticn)on forming taps increase their ability to work on harder material

Tags: threads

I understand that the coating(Tin,Ticn),on forming/cutting taps,drilling bits etc,makes them last longer,run cooler,drill smoother.
But does the coating on them increase their ability to work on harder material compare to the same one but with no coating?

For example:If i take three forming taps,exactly the same composition like HSSE(M35):

1. One without coating.
2. Second with Tin(Titanium-Nitride)coating.
3. Third with Ticn(Titanium Carbo-Nitride)coating.

Does the coating on the last two increase the ability of the forming taps to work on harder material compare to the uncoated one?

Comment: What do you mean by "harder material?" Do you mean harder as in moving from aluminum to bronze? Or do you mean from mild steel to hardened steel? I don't think you can form tap hardened steel because it's not ductile enough. You can always cut a really hard material by using something even harder but if a material can't be shoved around without cracking, it doesn't matter how hard the tool is. In general, if it didn't work at all before the coating then it will not work after the coating. If it did work before the coating, the correct coating might improve longevity and efficiency.

Comment: I read that the Tin coating has ~2600 HV vickers-hardness and the addition of carbon at Ticn coating add 33% to its hardness(~3500 HV).So if i understood your comment,the coating/hardness of the coating aren't related/not enhance anything to the ability of the tap/drill to work on harder material(i mean metals that can be shoved but harder in the rockwell scale)compare to the one with no coating.The uncoated tap can actually deal with the same hardness metals as Tin coating tap,which can deal with the same hardness metals as the Ticn metals,inspite the hardness of the coating.Am i correct?

Comment: Correct. It's like how case hardening reduces abrasive wear but doesn't really do make the material more dent or deformation resistant.